# How do I do a bulk insert into Oracle using C#?

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm trying to do a bulk insert to Oracle from C#. I have the data in an array list of objects. Currently inserting as:

```
using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(commandString, oc.connection))//, _transaction))
  {
     string[] temp = netstat.getStrings();

     //replace with nulls

     command.Parameters.Add("node", OracleType.VarChar, 255).Value = temp[0];
     command.Parameters.Add("protocol", OracleType.VarChar, 10).Value = temp[1];
     command.Parameters.Add("localip", OracleType.VarChar, 25).Value = temp[2];
     command.Parameters.Add("localport", OracleType.VarChar, 10).Value = temp[3];
     command.Parameters.Add("foreignip", OracleType.VarChar, 25).Value = temp[4];
     command.Parameters.Add("foreignport", OracleType.VarChar, 10).Value = temp[5];

     if (temp[6] == null)
       {
         command.Parameters.Add("state", OracleType.VarChar, 25).Value = DBNull.Value;
       }
     else
       {
         command.Parameters.Add("state", OracleType.VarChar, 25).Value = temp[6];
       }

     command.Parameters.Add("pid", OracleType.VarChar, 10).Value = temp[7];
     try
       {
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
     catch (OracleException e)
       {
         string errorMessage = "Code: " + e.Code + "\n" +
                               "Message: " + e.Message;

         //System.Diagnostics.EventLog log = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
         //log.Source = "My Application";
         //log.WriteEntry(errorMessage);
         Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred. Please contact your system administrator. " + errorMessage);
       }
  }
```

This is taking about 10 seconds per object! Is there a faster way to do this? I am using the Microsoft System.Data.OracleClient. Should i consider switching that? My goal is speed and application portability...I'm currently distributing the exe along with the oracle call interface DLLs so it will run without oracle installed.

Answer (score 1):

The MS client isn't very good.  You're better off with ODP.net

Comment: Would ODP.net enable me to keep the same portability? Or would additional files / an oracle install be needed to run this program?

Comment: Last time I used it you needed to install an oracle client.  Now you can do an xcopy deploy I believe